# Let A be a finite non-empty set and S a finite symbol set. Show that there are only finitely many S-structures with A as the domain

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Let A be a finite non-empty set and S a finite symbol set. Show that there are only finitely many S-structures with A as the domain

Let k be the number of elements in A,

for all constant symbols c in S there is k-many interpretations I(c).

Here's where I am a bit confused. I am having issues figuring out how many interpretations there would be for each n-ary function symbol f (and similarly for n-ary relation symbol R)

Comment: Well, what exactly *is* an n-ary function, in set-theoretic terms?  How would you list them all?

Comment: You'll probably have more luck with mathematical logic questions on math.SE.

Comment: belongs to mathematical logic / set theory. Not philosophical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an n-ary function symbol, there are k^n elements of the domain; for each one you need to choose one of k elements to send it to. So the total number of possible function interpretations would be k^(k^n).

For an n-ary relation, you have 2 possibilities for each of k^n possible n-ary lists. So what would be the total number of possible relation interpretations?